# Count users that have purchased different products within 30 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 user_id    product_type  reservation_date   used_date
|12345     |     A       |   2016-06-01    | 2016-06-24 |
|12345     |     B       |   2016-06-03    | 2016-06-24 |
|12345     |     C       |   2016-07-02    | 2016-07-30 |
|12346     |     A       |   2016-06-27    | 2016-07-24 |
|12346     |     B       |   2016-06-29    | 2016-07-22 |
```

I would like to figure out "cross selling" effect on our platform.
In the table above, `user_id` `12345` has purchased `product_type` `A`, `B`and `C` within a month (and a day).

I would like to count the number of users that have purchased any type of product, but at least 2 distinct types within the interval of 30 days in `reservation_date`.

Is there any way to do this? I've written a query like below but figured that this is inaccurate since I can't calculate the dates with the proper condition I would like to see the output of.

```
SELECT
DATE_TRUNC('month', reservation.date),
COUNT(DISTINCT(user.id)),
FROM reservation
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = reservation.product_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = reservation.user_id
WHERE products.type = 'A'
AND user.id IN(
SELECT user.id
FROM reservation
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = reservation.product_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = reservation.user_id
WHERE product.type in ('B','C')
GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Please define more closely: `with the interval of 30 days in reserved date` Is this the absolute time frame or is it the maximum interval between two distinct `product_type`? And always declare your version of Postgres. And `user.id` is not a valid column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this will do a job

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(r.user_id))
  FROM reservation r
 INNER JOIN reservation r_a
         ON r_a.user_id = r.user_id
        AND r_a.product_type <> r.product_type
        AND @extract(day FROM (r_a.reservation_date::TIMESTAMP - r.reservation_date::TIMESTAMP)) <= 30
```

`@extract(timepart from (one_timestamp - another_timestamp)` will equal the absolute value of "timeparts" in difference between two timestamps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. I tried this but in our reservation table, there's no "product type" column. I have to join the product type separately to the reservations table, Any other way around for this ? Would be really helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Oh.. now I see. So, in case when your data has strict one-to-one relationship between product_type and product_id you may just check not matching product_id's instead of product_type's in a query above. Else query will look like `... FROM reservation r INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = r.product_id INNER JOIN reservation r_a ON r_a.user_id = r.user_id AND @extract(..same params..) <=30 INNER JOIN products p_a ON p_a.id = r_a.product_id AND p_a.type <> p.type`.

Comment: Oh Yes this just calculated everything seamlessly :) 
Thank you so much, this is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic query could look like this (assuming you want to consider each month as time frame):

```
SELECT user_id, date_trunc('month', reservation_date)
     , count(DISTINCT product_type) AS ct
FROM   reservation
GROUP  BY 1,2
HAVING count(DISTINCT product_type) > 1
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```

To get the actual count of qualifying users:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM   reservation
   GROUP  BY user_id, date_trunc('month', reservation_date)
   HAVING count(DISTINCT product_type) > 1
   ) sub;
```

---

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381951/how-to-count-ids-per-condition-on-postgresql/37382215?noredirect=1#comment62275396_37382215):

> ... calculate monthly number of users who has made bookings ( at least 2
>   type of products ) with a gab between 30 days of each booking. So if I
>   made a booking on 1st for product A, and 15th for product B in July, I
>   am not counted in that monthly number.

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', reservation_date), count (DISTINCT user_id) AS ct_users
FROM   reservation r
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   reservation
   WHERE  user_id = r.user_id
   AND    reservation_date <= r. reservation_date - 30  -- assuming data type date!
   AND    product_type <> r.product_type
   )
GROUP  BY 1;
```

This returns the number of users per month than have made a reservation this month and at least one other reservation with a different type of product at least 30 days earlier.

Over a longer period of time it would be more efficient to remember users that qualified before and only test the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your input Erwin. I would like to calculate monthly number of users who has made bookings ( at least 2 type of products ) with a gab between 30 days of each booking. So if I made a booking on 1st for product A, and 15th for product B in July, I am not counted in that monthly number. I will try this! :)

Comment: @silverrain: The exact definition should really be *in the question*.